# C# Remove letter and number

Tags: c#

How to read random line from text file that startswith *

My text file has 15000 lines.Lines with * character are questions and lines below them are terms relating to that question.

This is one part of file:

```
*Planete i njihovi sateliti
Zemlja=Mesec
Mars=Fobos
Jupiter=Io
Saturn=Titan
Uran=Titania
Neptun=Triton
Pluton=Haron
Merkur=Nema satelit

*Francuski gradovi
Bordeaux=Bordo
Auxerre=Okser
Toulouse=Tuluz
Nantes=Nant
Marseille=Marselj
Dijon=Dižon
Limoges=Limož
Chateauroux=Šatero
```

http://pastebin.com/u8q4rimX

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly what you want, but maybe you could store all lines that start with * in a list structure and then generate a random number to access the items of that list.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some data structures where you want to the questions to be stored?

Comment: Do you just wish to get the question or the lines that follow as well?

Comment: Just question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all lines starting with `*` into a list, then get a random index.
And get rid of the `*` in the begining.

```
var questions = 
    File.ReadLines(filePath)
        .Where(line => line.StartsWith("*")).ToList();

var rng = new Random();
var myRandomQuestion = questions[rng.Next(questions.Count)].Substring(1);
```

**Update**

If you need the lines below as well, then the above won't work.
I first suggest that you create some sort of structure.
For example:

```
public class QuestionAndTerms
{
    public string Question {get; set;}
    public List<string> Terms {get; set;}
}
```

Then, loop through the file and fill a `List<QuestionAndTerms>`.

```
var question = null;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("*"))
    {
        if (question!= null) 
        {
            // We have a previous question
            questionList.Add(question);
        }

        question = new QuestionAndTerms();
        question.Question = line.Substring(1);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    {
        question.Terms.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Or loop through with `StremReader`

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    // loop and logic here

}
```

***All of the above is just to give a direction, it's neither test nor complete.***

Comment: Can you just tell me how to read lines below myRandomQuestion

Comment: Every question has 8 lines that relate to him ?How to read lines below random question

Comment: That's why i've asked you in the comments before posting if you need those lines as well... I will update my answer to give you a direction

Comment: Wow , thats interesting , great answer .

Comment: Where is delcared questionList

Comment: `questionList ` is of type `List<QuestionAndTerms>`. declare it before the loop or as a member somewhere in your context.

Answer (score 0):

First you must decide how you want the questions and responses to be represented as data structure. I suggest to represent questions and responses with adequate classes (I'm using VS 2017 / C# 7.0 syntax):

```
public class Choice
{
     public Choice (string choiceText, string answer)
     {
         ChoiceText = choiceText;
         Answer = answer;
     }

     public string ChoiceText { get; }
     public string Answer { get; }
}

public class Question
{
    public Question (string questionText)
    {
        QuestionText = questionText;
    }

    public string QuestionText { get; }
    public List<Choice> Choices { get; } = new List<Choice>();
}
```

Now you can start reading the file and put the questions and answers into the structures

```
var questions = new List<Question>();
var Question lastQuestion = null;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path)) {
    if (line.StartsWith("*")) {
        // We have a new question. Create a question object and add it to the list.
        lastQuestion = new Question(line.Substring(1));
        questions.Add(lastQuestion);
    } else if (lastQuestion != null) {
        // We have a term related to the last question. Add it to the last question.
        // Split the line at the equal sign.
        string[] parts = line.Split("=", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length > 0) {
            // We have at least one part that is not empty. Let’s assume it’s the part before
            // the "=". If we have a second part, insert it as well, otherwise insert null.
            var choice = new Choice(parts[0], parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : null);
            lastQuestion.Add(choice); 
        }
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that your example file contains 2 distinct types of questions. Some have the answer after the equal sign, while others have separated lists of choices and responses. So, you must expand the solution to take this into account.

Your question is very unspecific, so it is difficult to give you an appropriate answer. Next time, think in advance and ask a question that is more specific and more precise. Also, on Stack Overflow, we prefer when you provide a code example of what you have tried so far.